# SQL query to find duplicate orders with same invoice at the same address

Tags: mysql

I am trying to see how i can write a query to pull all the distinct permit numbers that have the same invoice numbers at the same address.
For Example i have below tables

**ADDRS Table**
ADD ID
MAIL ID
ORDER ID

**SRVC ADDRES TABLE**
MAIL ID
ST NBR
ST NAME
City
STATE

**ORDER TABLE**
ORDER ID
ORDER NBR
APPLY DATE

**ORDER FEES TABLE**
Order ID
FEEID
ORDR NBR

**INVOICE TABLE**
FEEID
INV ID
INV NBR
AMT

The SRVC ADDRESS TABLE has the address information. If there ST NBR and ST NAME columns has the same value then check the ADD TABLE to look for all distinct ORDER ID and then use the order table to select only APPLY DATE > '1/2/22' orders that has the same INV NBR from the INVOICE TABLE

Comment: Use `GROUP BY` and `COUNT(DISTINCT ORDER_ID)` and return the rows where the count is more than 1.

Comment: I think i am running into problem when i try to join the srvc address table  and addrs table when i want to look for the same values in both the st nbr and st name column. Is there a sample query that you may be able to share

Comment: Show what you tried and I'll help you fix it. I'm not going to write it for you.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would also help.